# unix - running a shell script in the background and creating an output log

Tags: bash, unix

What's the best way to run this shell script where I need to create an output log at the same time run it in the background? The catch is, I need to input a couple of parameters then enter a password.

For example I execute the shell script like so:

```
-bash-4.3$ ./tst.sh param1 param2 >> tst.log
Password for user mas:
```

I need to pass in (2) parameters, then prompted for a password:

```
./tsh.sh <param1> <param2>
```

This will work, but I have to keep the session open and I want it so it goes to the background or something similar where it will continue to run if my connection to the host fails..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to run something that will survive if your connection fails you should run it in a `screen` or `tmux` session.  You can use those to create sessions that you can disconnect from and reconnect to, and many other really cool things once you start really getting into them.

So if you `ssh` in and then run `screen` you'll still be at a bash prompt, but if you run a command then press `^a^d` you will detach from that session.  Everything running inside screen will keep going, and you'll be able to reconnect with `screen -x` later.  You can have many screen sessions at the same time too, use `screen -ls` to see which are running then you can use `screen -x <id>` to reconnect to a particular one.